# What is a word for a small pool?

Tags: word-choice

I was passing by a library and there were these very small (artificially created) bodies of water, square shaped, in a repeating pattern with some flowers also repeat between these bodies of water on the concrete in the middle of them.  There were ten of them or so.  They're probably six feet by six.  Looked maybe only a foot deep.

I don't know what one would call them.  Pond?  Small pool?  Basin?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Ornemental ponds ?

Comment: I wouldn't use small pool or basin, but pond could be partially correct (and probably preferable in some cases). However I think Phil has the best answer for this case.

Comment: I do not understand what bumped this question. There was no edit to the Q or the sole A, the sole A had already been upvoted, so the Q wasn't "unanswered". This happens with some frequency and it irritates me.

Answer (score 6):

In landscape architecture, they are called **water features**. Not very inspiring, but that's the way it goes sometimes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_feature

Comment: From the description in the question I think this is correct in this case, however it's also worth noting that __pond__ might be more suitable in some other cases.